# Seam component init method after request parameters are set

Tags: seam

I'm using an event-scope component as a view controller. I need to have an "init" method on that controller, where I can do authorization checks, load some entities from JPA, etc.

Problem is, if I choose to do that in a `@Create` method, parameters defined in `page.xml` are not yet set (via GET). `@RequestParameter` fields get set, but they are less flexible - can't use them in inner classes of the component, or just somewhere deeper down in a bean path. For example, I can direct `name=abc` to `#{controller.user.name}`, but can only use a component-level setter with `@RequestParameter`.

Is there another way to do an "init" method, where all request parameters are set, then?

Comment: I guess you mean Event scope, and not request scope. @RequestParameter normally get set from posting a form. Is that the case in your situation also?

Comment: GET request in this case. Yes, the event scope.

Comment: Why do you need a pre-authorization-check or pre-load some entities before you actually call the component? Couldn't you do these things just at the beginning of your controller-action(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution, after all. Moving project to Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can try this in u page.xml

```
<param name="xxx" value="#{component.xxx}"/>
<action execute="#{component.init}"/>
```